# Jquery datepicker validation is not working (without the use of datepicker by editing the textbox)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to validate `datepicker` as `startDate` should be always less than `EndDate`. If I change the date manually then `StartDate` works but `EndDate` does not work.

My `JavaScript` Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });
      $("#EndDate").datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

});
```

My .`cshtml` code

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter start date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter finish date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Can you add the entire view and your file reference??

Comment: @raj below is running example

Comment: @JibinBalachandran,In normal circumstance, it is working perfectly fine. But the problem arises only when we change `EndDate` manually. First please change start date manually by writing any date like `01/16/2010` before current date and it is taking the advantage of calendar to show that particular date in `StartDate` field but the same calendar is not working for `EndDate` when we change from current date to any date greater than the date provided like `01/22/2016`. Please guide me.

Comment: @Raj I didn't find any issue with your code.I have created a jsfiddle with the same. https://jsfiddle.net/Jibin/nh6eoj03/534/

Comment: @JibinBalachandran, Yes this fiddle is working as expected. But Please try to change `EndDate` manually, it is not taking an advantage of calendar.

Comment: @Raj Check my answer if you want a solution for manual change.I have added a jsfiddle link as well.Let me know if you still find any issues.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran, Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. It is a great help.

Comment: @Raj Can you edit the question and add what you mean by change the date manually so that it will be helpful for others.Normally when we say change date manually we assume that it's when the user changes date, which's not right in your case.In your case it's changing without using datepicker. I have added it in my answer but it would be better if you could add it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the dates to be changed manually(without the use of datepicker by editing the textbox), write an on change function and set the max value of datepickers accordingly.

Add the below functions to your js code.

```
$('#EndDate').on('change',function(){
    var selected=$('#EndDate').val();
    $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
});

 $('#StartDate').on('change',function(){
    var selected=$('#StartDate').val();
    $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6eoj03/538/)

Comment: Thann you @Jibin. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have created a similar demo which works.
Are you writing JavaScript code in head section of page i think , just write that same code end of your view will work.

> Model

```
public class DemoModel
{
    [Display(Name = "StartDate")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Choose StartDate")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "EndDate")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Choose EndDate")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

> View

```
@model DemoMVC.Models.DemoModel
    @{ Layout = null;}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/datetimepicker/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datetimepicker/jqueryui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/datetimepicker/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter start date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter finish date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        });
        $("#EndDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

> Output

[image: output]

Comment: `Enddate` is still not working properly as expected. First please change start date manually by writting any date like `01/16/2010` before current date and it is taking the advantage of calendar to show that particular date in `StartDate` field but the same calendar is not working for `EndDate` when we change from current date to any date greater than the date provided like `01/22/2016`. Please provide me proper guidance. In normal circumstance, it is working perfectly fine. But the problem arises only when we change `EndDate` manually.

Comment: @raj on keypress or keydown event do not allow user to enter date manually. show alert please choose date. if it help you please mark this as answer.

Comment: Is there any way where I can create a dropdown calendar so that user can select month and year from it. I think this will be easy in spite of doing manual change in date.

Comment: @raj it is not change in datepicker just a validation on textbox where you will not allow user to enter date just choose from datepicker.

Comment: @raj it is not change in datepicker just a validation on textbox where you will not allow user to enter date just choose from datepicker.